# How to format file log output with asp.net core and Serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I am testing some basic file logging with **Asp.Net Core** and I using Serilog as it's quick to setup.

The issue I having is when I log a message from the `HomeController` using the built in ILogger there is no mention of the controller in the file output. For example.. the logger is in the controller is like this and being injected the usual way in the constructor..

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
```

I am am logging something as a test like this

```
_logger.LogError("Test error log");
```

This appears in the file like this.. with no mention of HomeController.

2019-11-28T11:36:52.7735997+00:00 8000000c-0003-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] test info log (72772865)

Also where/how do I format this date so it isn't so long? Its not clear from the docs if its done in the json, or startup.cs. And I dont need the `8000000a-0003-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb` request id.

In `startup.cs` this is set up as follows

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/HPPartnerPortal-{Date}.txt");
```

My `config.json` specifies the default of

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"          
    }
```

I notice you can add File logging using the configure method in your startup.cs as I did above.. or you can add it in program.cs as specified in the

> https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file

like this

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            //we are setting up logging in Startup.cs so this is not needed ? !
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddDebug();                 
                //logging.AddFile("Logs/myapp-{Date}.txt"); -- AddFile not recognised?!
            })
```

The problem here is it doesnt recognise AddFile even though I have added 
Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File 
This is 1.1.0 which is the latest version in nuget.

Comment: The best place is to check the Serilog documentation. Please check [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output)

Comment: Sure, but that assumes you want to use their own static Log as opposed to ILogger. I think if its ILogger it must be specified in the config json under logging..

Comment: Serilog is another logging framework as the default, used by ASP.NET Core out of the box. When you want to use Serilog, you have to initialze and configure it as described in the documentation.

Comment: I am going to update this question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file#additional-configuration), this should set template in your appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    ...
    "OutputTemplate" : "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {RequestId,13} -[{Level:u3}] {Message} ({EventId:x8}){NewLine}{Exception}",
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried it but it didn't work for me. If anyone finds it working, please comment.

Edit.
Found the solution, you must install 2.0.0 version of extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the nuget package `Serilog.Extensions.Logging`
or you can modify the Project.json and add the following line:

```
"Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0"
```